# How to remove Starred tab in Gnome Nautilus with dconf?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, nautilus, dconf

Gnome Nautilus has this Starred tab that I don't use and want to remove:

[image]

How to do it with `dconf`? I believe there's an option to do it but couldn't find it yet.

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1359647/683161) to a similar question suggests taking too many low-level actions which I believe not needed. I think it all can be done with the help of `dconf` through the `gsettings` interface.